# wp_enqueue_script isn't working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have registered the following scripts in functions.php:

```
function jpmscripts() {
wp_register_script( 'adin-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/adin-slider.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_script( 'waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_script( 'skrollr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/skrollr.min.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_script( 'hammer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/hammer.min.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_script( 'jquery-hammer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jquery.hammer.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_script( 'imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/imagesloaded.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_script( 'jpm-home-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jpm-home.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_script( 'jpm-first-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jpm-first.js', array('jquery') );
 wp_register_style( 'jpm-home-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/jpm-home.css');
 wp_register_style( 'jpm-first-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/jpm-first.css');
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jpmscripts' );
```

And i have create a template file in my theme then i want to call my styles and scripts.i do

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: first
*/
?>
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
*
* Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
*/

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<?php

 wp_enqueue_style( 'sparkling-bootstrap');
 wp_enqueue_style( 'jpm-home-css' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded' );
 echo "string";
?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading" class="loading">
 ...
```

But nothing loaded. any styles any scripts....
pls help me.... im getting crazy

Answer (score 0):

You're *registering* them, but not *enqueueing* them...These are two different things.

You can simplify everything by simply using [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), which automatically registers scripts if you don't explicitly do it, and `wp_enqueue_style` for styles:

```
function jpmscripts() {
    // Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adin-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/adin-slider.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/skrollr.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hammer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/hammer.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-hammer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jquery.hammer.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/imagesloaded.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jpm-home-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jpm-home.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jpm-first-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/jpm-first.js', array('jquery') );

    // Styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jpm-home-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/jpm-home.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jpm-first-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/jpm-first.css');
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jpmscripts' );
```

Comment: Thank u so much. And how i can call them in my templat in footer ?

Comment: Add `true` as the final parameter to the `wp_enqueue_script`. For example: `wp_enqueue_script( 'adin-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/adin-slider.js', array('jquery'), null, true );`. More info about this parameter [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).